# Mounting and accessing Western Digital's MyCloud NAS

Tags: mount, lubuntu, 13.10, nfs

I have bought a Western Digital Mycloud disk. I did succeed to mount it under Lubuntu 13.10 by means of the following command:

```
sudo mount -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192 
<IP address>:/nfs /home/myusername/nfs/
```

Afterwards I do see the various shares in the directory nfs.

Unfortunately however I do not get access to the files. This is because the Western Digital device needs a username and password.

I am a Linux rookie so would there be someone willing to tell me how to specify these in the mount command?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

AFP is Apple File Protocol which, along with Samba, is natively supported by the WD NAS server. You can also use smbfs or cifs on your Linux box and mount the shares permanently (see [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/MountWindowsSharesPermanently)) or you can use NFS. NFS, particularly udp, offers better performance but poorer security. I use NFS because file ownership and permissions are an important issue to me and they are not fully supported in smbfs/cifs.

I have just posted a how-to to set up NFS between a Linux client running 14.04 and a WD Own Cloud NAS server - see [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219544).

Comment: You should not use NFS with UDP.  Not because it would be less secure, but because it's not unlikely that you will lose data on fast modern networks.

Comment: Also, you should post answers here on the site, not (only) elsewhere with a link to a site that might disappear in the future.

Comment: You will not "lose data" using NFS with UDP. IBM states “NFS normally uses the UDP protocol (at R610 and above it can also use TCP)." The reference to R610 is the version of AIX, IBM's implementation of UNIX. UDP is used in HACMP environments (High Availability Clustered Multi Processing), Note the first two words. If data would likely be lost, it would not be suited to a high availability environment. TCP will be faster on a busy commercial network, but a system where a WD MyCloud is going to be will almost certainly be on a relatively quiet home network where UDP will outperform TCP.

Comment: I do not agree on your statement regarding links to other sites where, as in this case, the link is to Ubuntu Forums. I don't think it is likely to disappear in the future, it would make more work and also cause unnecessary duplication.

Comment: My references for quotes from IBM are: https://www-304.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=nas8N1016376  and  http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-aix7networkoptimize2/

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple in Linux, you just need to specify the username and password in your options, I modified your statement to be as follows:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,username=UUUUUUU 
<IP address>:/nfs /home/myusername/nfs/
```

Whereas UUUUUUU is your username.

Notice that I also added "-t cifs" whereas cifs is the standard type to connect to these drives.

This will prompt you to enter a password for user UUUUUUU, if however, you like to pass the password parameter as well, then just add it into the options in the same way, below is the full statement:

```
sudo mount -t cifs -o soft,intr,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,username=UUUUUUU,password=PPPPPPPP 
<IP address>:/nfs /home/myusername/nfs/
```

I hope this helps.