# NAS Support For Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, mount, backup, nas

I've purchased the 'Western Digital MyBook Live 2TB Personal Cloud Storage'.  It supports NAS.  I am trying to setup automatic backups.  (Something like rysnc which may run daily to backup my `/home` folder.

I found [this thread](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1603439) giving the instruction:

```
sudo apt-get install pyNeighborhood
```

This is from 2010. I am getting the error

```
Unable to locate package pyNeighborhood
```

I don't want to risk corrupting my Ubuntu 16.04 desktop. Is there a similar  package that is suitable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, you can browse the content of network disk "out-of-the-box" in Ubuntu, e.g., via Samba (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> in Nautilus and put `smb://hostname` (or `IP`) in the address bar). The same can be obtained with afp, sshfs.

If you want to use it as backup, I recommend some of the "supported" programs. See https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem

Comment: I want to use *rsync*

Comment: I guess to use rsync you will have to have network disk always mounted (or at least at the time rsync is executed). In order to achieve this see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/420455/mounting-and-accessing-western-digitals-mycloud-nas and https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2219544

Answer (score 1):

Just based on your `Unable to locate package pyNeighborhood` error, something's wrong since the [pyneighborhood package is still in the Ubuntu repositories](https://packages.ubuntu.com/bionic/pyneighborhood) for   trusty,  xenial, artful, and  bionic.

Do you have a regular Ubuntu software source (in `/etc/apt/sources` or  `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/`) and have you done an `apt-get update` before attempting install? It should work.

Comment: It was case sensitive!  sudo apt install pyneighborhood

Comment: There's that too, I use Synaptic so there's very little typing required. Or if using apt-get it can tab-complete packages & commands, so that's another double-check.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion I think that the capital "N" in the file name caused that error. You need to run this command instead:

```
sudo apt-get install pyneighborhood
```